# PHP exec() Function Creates 1000s of Processes on Server :(

Tags: php, linux, command-line

I am trying to trigger a PHP script from another PHP script using exec() function. On my local system, it triggers the other script. But, when I execute it on server, it creates 1000s of processes & they are running in background :( Here is the reason why I have to do this.

I am sending SMS via PHP script. This PHP script is executed via Command Prompt on server. Now, to test SMS functionality, I have to wait for someone to execute my SMS PHP script on server via Command Prompt.

So, I have written a script, execute.php, with only one statement,

```
exec('php index.php');
```

to trigger my SMS PHP script, index.php.

I hit execute.php from browser. But, browser just waits for the server & multiple processes are created on server which ultimately slows down the server.

Please help :(

Comment: Why can't you just use `include index.php` in the code of the php page serving the request?

Comment: My index.php file must execute via Command Prompt coz its sending SMS via SMPP protocol (with Kannel SMS Gateway). So, I can't use `include` as this will not execute it via Command Prompt. The file will be just included & Kannel SMS Gateway won't be able to take up the execution.